# Script won't execute in html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a header created in index.html and a separate page in test.html. I'm able to use scripts on the index.html page but not on the test.html page I can't seem to find out why.

In the following file the console log logs the test statement and i'm able to see it in the browser.

Index.html:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Main Angular Files -->
    <script src="assets/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/angular-animate.js"></script>



    <!-- Angular Config/Routes -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/routes.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Controllers -->
    <script src="app/controllers/userCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/emailCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/managementCtrl.js"></script>


    <script> console.log('test'); </script>    

    <!-- Angular Services -->
    <script src="app/services/userServices.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/authServices.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Cascade Style Sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/animate.css">




    <title>MEAN Stack App</title>

</head>

<body ng-app="userApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl as main" ng-show="main.loadme" ng-cloak>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-shrink">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="/">MEAN Stack</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden active">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a ng-show="!main.isLoggedIn" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a ng-show="!main.isLoggedIn" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="/dashboard/{{ main.userid }}">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="/mytests/{{ main.userid }}">My tests</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="/comments">Comments</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="/subscriptions">Subscriptions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="/recruitafriend">Invite friend and earn MONEY</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Hello {{ main.username }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="">
                            <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="#" ng-click="main.logout();">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn && main.authorized" class="page-scroll" href="/management">Management</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn && main.authorized" class="page-scroll" href="/orders">Orders</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="/profile">Hello {{ main.username }}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a ng-show="!main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a ng-show="!main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="#">Help</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a ng-show="!main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="/login">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a ng-show="!main.isLoggedIn" class="page-scroll" href="/register">Register</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
    <header ng-show="main.home">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro-text">
                <div class="intro-lead-in">David Acosta</div>
                <div class="intro-heading">MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, NodeJS</div>
                <a ng-show="!main.isLoggedIn" href="/login" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Sign In</a>
                <a ng-show="!main.isLoggedIn" href="/register" class="page-scroll btn twitterbtn">Register</a>
                <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn" href="#" ng-click="main.logout();" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Logout</a>
                <a ng-show="main.isLoggedIn && main.authorized" href="/management" class="page-scroll btn facebookbtn">View</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <!-- Angular View -->
                <div ng-view></div>
                <!-- Angular View -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
    <section ng-show="main.home" id="portfolio" class="bg-light-gray">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">

                    <h2 class="section-heading">About This Page</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span>
                    <h4 class="service-heading">YouTube</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Ensure you check out the YouTube video series associated with this web page. Visit:
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3vQyqzqjZ637sWpKvniMCxdqZhnMJC1d" target="_blank">https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3vQyqzqjZ637sWpKvniMCxdqZhnMJC1d</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>
                    <h4 class="service-heading">Facebook</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>
                    <h4 class="service-heading">Github</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted">Ensure you check out the GitHub page associated with this web page. Visit:
                        <a href="https://github.com/gugui3z24" target="_blank">https://github.com/gugui3z24</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer ng-show="main.home">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span class="copyright">Copyright © David Acosta</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <ul class="list-inline quicklinks">
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- BootstrapJS Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button ng-hide="main.hideButton" type="button" ng-click="main.endSession();" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{ main.modalHeader }}</h4>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal Body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>{{ main.modalBody }}</p>
                    <div ng-show="main.hideButton" class="dizzy-gillespie"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <!-- Modal 'Yes' & 'No' Buttons -->
                    <button type="button" ng-hide="main.hideButton" ng-click="main.renewSession();" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                    <button type="button" ng-hide="main.hideButton" ng-click="main.endSession();" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BootstrapJS Modal -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The test.html won't execute the code within the script tags. But the h1 will show.

Test.html:

```
<div>

 <h1> Hello Test </h1> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('2');
  </script>


</div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: What browser are you using? And are you sure the console is empty? What  does `Ctrl+Shift+J` (in Google Chrome) show in the console. Also, try `alert()` instead of `console.log()`

Comment: if you can see errors in console the rest of JS code will not work , provide your console log too

Comment: No errors in the console.

I'm using Chrome, I've checked the console numerous times trying to scroll up and down and seeing nothing within it. 

Since no errors are shown in the console i cannot provide its content.

Comment: @Oscar can you test by adding jquery file before angular.

Comment: That solved it! How come that was a problem?

Comment: @Oscar it is jQuery or jqLite issue. I have added answer below

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you do not use `jquery`, `Angular` uses `jqlite`. once view is loaded, than inspect it in chrome. You will not find `script` tag in view.Because Angular don't what to do with script tag hence removes it. When angular detects `jquery`, it will use jquery instead `jqlite` for dom manipulation and `jquery`   treat the `script` tag as special.

```
< <script src="path/jquery.js"></script>   
<!-- Main Angular Files -->
<script src="assets/js/angular.js"></script>

<div>
 <h1> Hello Test </h1> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('2');
  </script>

</div>
```